# rxjs combineLatest not working as expected

Tags: rxjs

I am struggling with the 'combineLatest' operator...
I have a operator chain like so:

```
    const observable = interval(1000).pipe(
  map((x) => 'myAction'),
  mergeMap((action)=>
    combineLatest([from([1,2,3]),of(action)])
  ),
  tap(result=>{
    console.log('-');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
  })
);
```

I would expect this output:

```
[1, 'myAction']
[2, 'myAction']
[3, 'myAction']
```

what i get is just one output:

```
[3, 'myAction']
```

How can I achieve to get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggests, combine latest only combines the most recent emissions for the given streams. Since from([1,2,3]) is synchronous, (effectively emits all its values at once), you can get some hard to predict behavior. I haven't tested this, but you may be able to switch the order of the observable and it might work as expected (since `of(action)` gets subscribed to first).

How I would solve this case:

Since `of(action)` is just wrapping a single value, I wouldn't bother. Just map the value into your observable directly. That might look like this:

```ts
const observable = interval(1000).pipe(
  map(x => 'myAction'),
  mergeMap(action => of(1,2,3).pipe(
    map(n => [n, action])
  )),
  tap(result=>{
    console.log('-');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
  })
);
```

Comment: Yes, placing the from([1,2,3]) last actually worked! But just mapping the single values is also a good (actually the better) suggestion!

Comment: @joachim_b :) Unlike pull based libraries (generators/streams) where wrapping synchronous values makes a lot of sense (a wrapped array is a natural buffer), it's less common to do this with RxJS. In most cases, synchronous code is thrown in a function and passed to an operator.